# adding upload file interface to my solr browser

Tags: apache, file-upload, solr, solr4

I am new to solr 4.0.
I already made a custom browser site.

1)I want to add an upload file interface to it, so clients can upload their own files from home.
2)After a file is being uploaded i want to parse and edit it with a jar application i made.

The only i can think of with my knowledge is run my parser every few minutes and using SolrJ search for a new document to parse and update.

I saw there is a smarter way, using 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#EventListeners
But i don't understand how to run my own jar file.

Comment: what kind of parse and edit are you doing ?

Comment: First i use tika to convert the file to text and than i use a topic-based summarizer i made, and i need to store its output with the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options you can check upon :-

1. Use Solrj to post the Contents to Solr
2. Build a Custom filter or Analyzer which would use the jar build for Topic based Summarizer
3. Copyfield the text to an other field which would use this Filter to populate the values.

Also, you can check with DIH if you can use a Custom Transformer(which would use the jar) with the field to transform the contents.

Comment: Thx. I will read about it. do you have idea if its possible to add file upload interface as well?

Comment: thats a part of the client application and should not be in solr.

Comment: I thought solr have some kind of skeleton for that (can't install anything on the server). So my server must support PHP/ASP too for that?

Comment: Solr does not provide an file upload screens. It just provides you rest/http apis for support files. SO you should have a separate application for that functionality